# ¿Procedimiento para Liberación de espacio en una base de datos SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

he armado el siguiente script para liberar espacio de todas las bases de datos de un servidor, como sabrán esto es posible si se introduce el código dentro del Procedimiento `sp_MSforeachdb`, la variable que indica en qué base de datos se encuentra es `[?]`. Bueno, en el código se indican 3 restricciones, he separado como caso particular el `tempdb` por que no acepta la sentencia `alter ... recovery`, el segundo caso es sobre una base de datos (`BD_PRODUCT`) que tiene 4 archivos log y 4 de data (solo estoy tomando los 2 últimos de cada tipo) y por último el caso general (lo que queda). El problema que tengo con el flujo que quiero manejar con los `if...else` es que no me funciona cuando toca "jugar" con el `tempdb`, que no respeta el último `else` y me arroja un mensaje de error indicándome que no debo aplicarle el `alter...recovery` que era justamente la razón por la cual se le había separado en un caso particular.

```
            EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 
            '
                use [?]

                declare 
                @arch_1 sysname,
                @arch_2 sysname,
                @bd_name sysname

                set @bd_name=(select DB_NAME())
                set @arch_1 =(select name FROM SYSFILES
                              where fileid = ''1'')
                set @arch_2 =(select name FROM SYSFILES
                              where fileid = ''2'')

                if (@bd_name=''tempdb'')
                begin
                    select name from sysfiles

                    DBCC SHRINKFILE (tempdev, 1)
                    DBCC SHRINKFILE (templog, 1)
                end

                else
                begin
                    if (@bd_name=''BD_PRODUCT'')
                    begin
                        select name from sysfiles

                        ALTER DATABASE BD_PRODUCT
                        SET RECOVERY SIMPLE

                            DBCC SHRINKFILE (BD_PRODUCT4 , 1);
                            DBCC SHRINKFILE (BD_PRODUCT_log4 , 1);

                        ALTER DATABASE BD_PRODUCT
                        SET RECOVERY FULL
                    end

                    else
                    begin
                        select name from sysfiles

                        ALTER DATABASE [?]
                        SET RECOVERY SIMPLE

                            DBCC SHRINKFILE (@arch_1 , 1)
                            DBCC SHRINKFILE (@arch_2 , 1)

                        ALTER DATABASE [?]
                        SET RECOVERY FULL
                    end
                end
            '
```

Por ende quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de evitar este inconveniente, por que quisiera tener este código como un Store pero aún tengo este problema.

Saludos.

Comment: Esta no es una buena forma de disminuir el espacio de las bases de datos. Básicamente estás truncando el log y haciendo un "srhink" de los datos....que lo más probable es que la base de datps simplemente vuelva a reservar ese espacio casi instantáneamente

Comment: ¿Entonces solo me recomiendas hacer esta operación para el archivo log? ¿Y qué hay con el problema del flujo, por que sigue leyendo el último alter si lo he restringido con un ´else´?

Comment: No recomiendo hacer ningún paso de esto. El log se debería limpiar automáticamente cuando haces un backup de la base de datos

Comment: Lo que sucede es que la carga sobre una base de datos durante el día es alta, se corren procesos (Jobs) de carga de datos, y el proceso principal (semanal) dura 14 a más horas y el tema del espacio siempre es un problema, por lo que siempre se recurre a la liberación de espacio antes de activar el JOB (Proceso a demanda).

Comment: la liberación de espacio que obtienes de truncar el log puedo entenderlo, pero debería ocurrir al hacer un backup de la base de datos. Hacerlo de esta forma puede dejar la base de datos en estado sospechoso o corrupto

Comment: Entonces estudiaré más a detalle el tema de la liberación de espacio, ¿pero hay alguna solución concreta para ese error que me arroja el script?